# Receive numbers till the input is number that % 7 is without remainder

Tags: javascript, zero

i got the next exercise in Javascript:

Receive whole numbers from the user, until he enters a number that % 7 with no remainder.
For each number received, state whether it is positive, negative or 0.
when inserting a number % by 7 with no remainder, end the program.

here is my code:

```
let num = +prompt("give us a number")
while (num % 7 != 0) {

    if (num > 0){
        document.write("positive ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    } else if (num < 0) {
        document.write("negative ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    } else if (num === 0) {
        document.write("zero ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    }
```

The thing is, when the user enter 0 ,obviously i wont get output "zero", cause 0 % 7 is 0 remainder, so it dosent even get into the loop..so how can i output "zero" when the user enter 0?

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: This is javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
let num = +prompt("give us a number")
while (num % 7 != 0) {

    if (num > 0){
        document.write("positive ")
        if(num % 7 == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        num = +prompt("give us a number") 
    } 
    } else if (num < 0) {
        document.write("negative ")
        if(num % 7 == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        num = +prompt("give us a number") 
    } 
    } else if (num === 0) {
        document.write("zero ")
        if(num % 7 == 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        num = +prompt("give us a number") 
    } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution didn't work, its kind of mine, with your code, if the user first input is 0 , its immediately shut down the program, cause 0 % 7 is = zero, so you even dont get into the loop

Answer (score 0):

Either bring out the `else if (num == 0)` part before `while` loop

> since `0 % 7 == 0` is `true` it should satisfy the excersise even if it's not in the loop.

```
if (num == 0) {
  // do stuff
}
while (/* condition */) {
  // do other stuff
}
```

Or add `num == 0` constraint in `while` condition.

```
while (num == 0 || num % 7 != 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

The former will not get into the loop, the latter will cause the loop to exit on `num == 0` because both implies that it's a correct modulo division.

You can do both if you want to optimize memory usage (obviously it wouldn't be a problem in this scale).

Comment: If i would bring out the else if (num == 0) part before while loop, i will get the output string "zero" only if the first input is 0! but if say, the first input is 1 >> it gets into the loop, and now the user input is 0 the program will stop without print "zero"

Answer (score 0):

This may be one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Sample**
This sample uses `alert` to pop-up the result, instead of `document.write`.

```
let num = 1;
while (!num || num % 7) {
  num = +prompt('enter a number');
  if (num && num % 7) {
    alert(
      `${num} is ${num > 0
        ? 'positive'
        : 'negative'
      }`
    );
  } else if (!num) alert('num is zero');
};
```

**Explanation**

- Set an initial value of `num` to `1`
- Set a `while` loop which will execute as long as `num` is not 0 (falsy, technically) and `num % 7` is not 0.
- Get the user-input using `prompt` into the variable `num`
- If `num` is truthy (ie, non-zero) and `num % 7` is truthy (ie, non-zero), pop an `alert` whether `num` is positive (if > 0) or negative (otherwise). This is achieved by using ` [backtick symbol / template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and `?:` [ternary-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- Else, if `num` is zero, then pop-up corresponding `alert`

**Code Snippet**

```js
let num = 1;
while (!num || num % 7) {
  num = +prompt('enter a number');
  if (num && num % 7) {
    alert(
      `${num} is ${num > 0
        ? 'positive'
        : 'negative'
      }`
    );
  } else if (!num) alert('num is zero');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it turned out, this this the simplest answer:

```
let num = +prompt("give us a number")
while (**num == 0| num % 7 != 0**) {
    if (num > 0){
        document.write("positive ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    } else if (num < 0) {
        document.write("negative ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    } else if (num === 0) {
        document.write("zero ")
        num = +prompt("give us a number" )
    }      
}
```